# List all results from a particular table after filtering the other table with a WHERE statement

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to create a simple blog-like newsreel for a webpage. For that, I have three tables: One that contain the posts, other with the categories, and another that links posts with categories (called 'relation').

I've been able to manage most of the queries, but one still eludes me: The category blogroll. The main problem is that I want to list all the relations from each particular post, but because I'm filtering by a particular relation, of course it only shows this one.

Example:
table 1 (POSTS):

```
POST_ID POST_TITLE POST_CONTENT
1       TEST       TEST
2       TES2       TEST2
```

table 2 (Categories):

```
CAT_ID CAT_NAME
1      NEWS
2      PRODUCTS
```

table 3 (Relations):

```
REL_POST REL_CAT
1        1
1        2
2        2
```

So, Post 1 belongs to both 'news' and 'products', and if I ask for a blogroll of the 'products' category, this should be the output:

```
POST_ID POST_TITLE POST_CONTENT POST_CATEGORIES
1       TEST       TEST         1:NEWS,2:PRODUCTS
2       TES2       TEST2        2:PRODUCTS
```

Instead of that, POST_CATEGORIES only lists 2:PRODUCTS, as I filtered for queries by REL_CAT.

Here is the sample code I managed to make:

```
SELECT `post_id`, `post_title`, `post_content`, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(rel_cat,':', cat_name)) AS post_categories
FROM `posts`
LEFT JOIN `relations` ON (`rel_post` = `post_id`)
LEFT JOIN `categories` ON (`cat_id` = `rel_cat`)
WHERE rel_cat = 2
```

Can someone point me what I'm doing wrong? I've tried to consult the manuals and search the web, but most results point me to people that has the reverse problem (they want to filter the results from a joined table), and mysql manual could be written in obfuscated PERL for what I've read.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to list everything in the `PRODUCTS` category, but include all their other categories as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have extra join on `RELATION` table since you want to search for the `post` that contains specific `category` and you want to display all categories for that `post`.

```
SELECT  a.post_id, 
        a.post_title, 
        a.post_content, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(b.rel_cat,':', c.cat_name)) AS post_categories
FROM    posts a
        INNER JOIN relations b
            ON b.rel_post = a.post_id
        INNER JOIN categories c
            ON c.cat_id = b.rel_cat
        INNER JOIN RELATIONS d  
            ON  a.POST_ID = d.REL_POST  AND 
                d.REL_CAT = 2               -- <<== SEARCH HERE
GROUP   BY a.post_id, a.post_title, a.post_content
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f80d9/9)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦══════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ POST_ID ║ POST_TITLE ║ POST_CONTENT ║  POST_CATEGORIES  ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║       1 ║ TEST       ║ TEST         ║ 1:NEWS,2:PRODUCTS ║
║       2 ║ TES2       ║ TEST2        ║ 2:PRODUCTS        ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩══════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
SELECT `post_id`, `post_title`, `post_content`, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(rel_cat,':', cat_name)) AS post_categories
FROM `posts`
    LEFT JOIN `relations` ON (`rel_post` = `post_id`)
    LEFT JOIN `categories` ON (`cat_id` = `rel_cat`)
GROUP BY `post_id`
```

You need to remove your `WHERE` criteria to get both/all categories and add `GROUP BY`.

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd417/2)

---

If you are trying to filter only those posts that have a specific cat, but show all the cats for that post, then you need to join on the table again:

```
SELECT post_id, post_title, post_content, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(r.rel_cat,':', cat_name) ORDER BY r.rel_cat) AS post_categories
FROM posts
    LEFT JOIN relations r ON (r.rel_post = post_id)
    LEFT JOIN categories ON (cat_id = r.rel_cat)
    INNER JOIN relations r2 ON (r2.rel_post = post_id )
WHERE r2.rel_cat = 2
GROUP BY post_id
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd417/7)

Comment: Thanks. I never though on trying to join the table again. Seems that I have much to learn yet :)

Comment: @Stormbolter -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `post_id`, `post_title`, `post_content`, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cat_id,':', cat_name)) AS post_categories
FROM `posts`
    JOIN `relations` r1 ON (r1.`rel_post` = `post_id`)
    JOIN `relations` r2 ON (r2.`rel_post` = `post_id`)
    JOIN `categories` ON (`cat_id` = r2.`rel_cat`)
WHERE r1.`rel_cat` = 2
GROUP BY `post_id`
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2bee/2)