# problems using GROUP_CONCAT in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, group-concat

i have the following tables:

**posts**: id, title, date, content

**tags**: id, name

**posts_tags**: post_id, tag_id

I want to select the title with a list of related tags; the following query works nicely

```
SELECT p.title, GROUP_CONCAT( t.name ORDER BY t.name SEPARATOR ',' ) as tags_list
FROM posts AS p
JOIN posts_tags AS pt ON pt.post_id = p.id
JOIN tags AS t ON pt.tag_id = t.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

with this query i get something that looks like this

```
title             |  tags_list
==================|===============================
Old cinema        |  film,movies
cooking shows     |  cooking,food,kitchen,television
Epic War Films    |  history,movies,war
Art in France     |  art,france,history
```

when I want to only posts with a certain tag (for example "movies") I tried adding a where clause:

```
SELECT p.title, GROUP_CONCAT( t.name ORDER BY t.name SEPARATOR ',' ) as tags_list
FROM posts AS p
JOIN posts_tags AS pt ON pt.post_id = p.id
JOIN tags AS t ON pt.tag_id = t.id
WHERE t.name = 'movies'
GROUP BY p.id
```

i end up with this

```
title            |  tags_list
=================|===============================
Old cinema       |  movies
Epic War Films   |  movies
```

I got all the posts tagged "movies", but the problem is the "tags_list" column only shows "movies" in each row instead of including all the other tags associated with the post.

how can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List all results from a particular table after filtering the other table with a WHERE statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826138/list-all-results-from-a-particular-table-after-filtering-the-other-table-with-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition need to be put on the result of `GROUP_CONCAT` not on each row so as @AshwinMukhija suggested the condition needs to be in `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT 
    p.title, 
    GROUP_CONCAT( t.name ORDER BY t.name SEPARATOR ',' ) as tags_list
FROM 
    posts AS p
JOIN posts_tags AS pt 
    ON pt.post_id = p.id
JOIN tags AS t 
    ON pt.tag_id = t.id
GROUP BY 
    p.id
HAVING
    FIND_IN_SET('movies',tags_list)
```

`FIND_IN_SET` returns true if the string movies is found in the comma separated list `tags_list`

Comment: thanks Stephan, works great. I think Ashwin had the right idea with "having", but using having with FIND_IN_SET is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to shift the condition on your tag from the `where` clause to `having`

```
SELECT p.title, GROUP_CONCAT( t.name ORDER BY t.name SEPARATOR ',' ) as tags_list
FROM posts AS p
JOIN posts_tags AS pt ON pt.post_id = p.id
JOIN tags AS t ON pt.tag_id = t.id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING t.name = 'movies'
```

Comment: Hi Ashwin, when I use this query I get the error: #1054 - Unknown column 't.name' in 'having clause'